# Lap cannot be installed

Tags: python, yolo

```
iles (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tplap\_lapjv.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\lap\_lapjv.obj /Zm1000" failed with exit status 2
      INFO:
      ########### EXT COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
      INFO: Platform      :
        Architecture: x64
        Compiler    : msvc

      CPU baseline  :
        Requested   : 'min'
        Enabled     : SSE SSE2 SSE3
        Flags       : none
        Extra checks: none

      CPU dispatch  :
        Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
        Enabled     : SSSE3 SSE41 POPCNT SSE42 AVX F16C FMA3 AVX2 AVX512F AVX512CD AVX512_SKX AVX512_CLX AVX512_CNL AVX512_ICL
        Generated   : none
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[857] : write cache to path -> C:\Users\dell6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vppdq7c3\lap_611fff53ba4c402795b76eb91d9693f4\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lap
  Running setup.py clean for lap
Failed to build lap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I just tried pip install in cmd. I want to install lap.